# Overheating/high CPU usage by Windows virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, overheating

I am running Kubuntu 14.04 as a host and windows 7 in a VirtualBox. The latter is using ~30% of my CPU and overheats the CPU to 94°C. This does not seem healthy.

What is going on here and how can I fix it?

PS: I found something similar in case of a Mac: http://kb.parallels.com/en/123268

Comment: Not only guest is using CPU power, so what is the CPU usage reported in the host system? And if you are trying to tune CPU usage of Windows, please try [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

At 30% in any case should get this temp.

In my modest opinion this can be one of this three problems:

1) your sensors are not right or they are getting wrong info.

2) your hardware needs a mantenience, clean up fans, heatshinks, case and  change termal paste of the CPU/GPU.

3) if your temp is right in normal scenarios this will be a software related, whitch will need more info to be solved.

Comment: Yes, normally the temperature is ok. This seems software related to me. Which kind of information would be helpful to solve the issue and how to I get it?

Comment: @Make42 when you say normally the temp is ok, what exacly do you mean? (Hypervisors have high load CPU/disk and sometimes GPU asswell). Have you try to reach that 30% CPU without the hypervisor (virtualbox) and checked the temp? Also did you check the GPU load/temp? What about hdd temp? Try checking this temps and post results. Also you can try other Hypervisors and see if they have same behavior.